# Uploading File to specific Google Drive Folder using expo-app-auth

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api, expo

I've been struggling with this for two days now and don't know where else to turn. Essentially I am using expo-app-auth to take care of getting the access token from google to be able to upload and then I am making a simple fetch request using said token. It all works fine except everytime the file gets uploaded to the authenticated user's root google drive directory instead of the folder id which I passed into the metadata of the formData object being sent through the post request.

Below I have attached the relevant code for uploading (not including the authentication because I know that works fine). Any help would be appreciated and TYIA.

```
const uploadFile = async (file) => {
if (file) {

  const filename = file.name;
  const folderid = [REDACTED];

  const metadata = {
    name: filename,
    parents: ["1Qu1IIsQJjAE131w97tLVM5FlTtExEQ1K"],
    mimeType: file.mimeType,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
  };
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("metadata", new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: "application/json" }));

  formData.append("file", file);



  fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/related",
      },
      body: formData,
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
else{
  Alert.alert("Please select a file to upload")
}
```

};

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by `"except every time the file gets uploaded to the authenticated user's root Google Drive directory instead of the folder ID that I passed into the metadata of the formData object being sent through the POST request"`? Kindly provide the expected results, a screenshot of the issue (if available), or any similar data to help the community visualize the complete issue you are facing. This will assist others in better understanding your problem and providing appropriate solutions.

Comment: When the uploadFile function is called, it successfully uploads the selected file to the authenticated user's Google Drive, however not to the folder that was passed in.

I get the following response from res:
`{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "[REDACTED]",
  "name": "Untitled",
  "mimeType": "application/pdf"
}
` 

The fact that the name is untitled is further evidence that the metadata is not being parsed correctly. Furthermore, the file is going into the user's google drive in the wrong location since the folderid in the metadata is not being properly recognized.